# MiKTeX 2.9 - updated packages change the desired result

Tags: fonts

On a Windows 10 Pro (up-to-date) environment I have installed the latest MiKTeX 2.9.7342-x64 after de-installing and removing all traces of the older MiKTeX 2.9 installation. However

```
pdflatex <filename>.tex
```

now produces different (incorrect) results (even though the .tex file is the same).  Here is a snippet I now get in the PDF file:

[image]

Using my laptop that has an older version of MiKTeX (2.9.7342-x64 was installed; the console says 2.9.7076) I see the correct PDF - here is a snippet:

[image]

The *scriptsize* font is a bit wider and more legible - especially the degrees symbol. How could this have changed? The source file is identical. I only allowed the necessary packages to be installed by MiKTeX. It's a clean installation. Isn't stuff like this standardised so you know you'll always get the same output from the same (LaTeX) input?

I performed another test: on my latop (where I get correct results), I checked for updates. Only these USER MODE were listed:

```
miktex-synctex-bin-x64-2.9
miktex-lcdf-typetools-bin-x64-2.9
```

In ADMIN mode 122 packages needed to be updated. I updated all these too. Here comes the **"acid test"** - I rerun the *pdflatex* command. It now requires these packages to be installed:

```
I3kernel
iftex
I3backend
epstopdf-pkg
infwarerr
grfext
kvdefinekeys
kvoptions
ltxcmds
kvsetkeys
pdftexcmds
modes
```

... and I now get the same incorrect result on my laptop as I had on my PC. So updating MiKTeX had a negative effect.

- is there a known "fix" for my *incorrect font* issue?
- or is there a way to revert to the older packages?
- how can one maintain workable TeX code if the packages keep on changing? (especially as this gets published on GitHub)

**EDIT:** Here is a shortened version of the TEX file that produced the correct/desired PDF and now produces the snippet as described above (excuse the formatting - it's from rather old code):

```
\documentclass[10pt, twoside, a4paper]{report}
    \usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[english]{babel}
    \usepackage{fontenc}
    \usepackage[ top=21mm, bottom=21mm, left=16mm, right=10mm]{geometry}
    \newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}
    \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{titlepage}
    \begin{center}

    \textsc{\Large Generated by PyAlmanac}\\[1.5cm]

    \textsc{\huge The Nautical Almanac for the Sun}\\[0.7cm]

        \HRule \\[0.6cm]
        { \Huge \bfseries from 3.5.2020}\\[0.4cm]
        \HRule \\[1.5cm]

        \begin{center} \large
        \emph{Author:}\\
        Enno \textsc{Rodegerdts}\\
\end{center}

    \vfill

    {\large \today}
    \HRule \\[0.6cm]
    \end{center}

    \begin{description}\footnotesize

    \item[Disclaimer:] These are computer generated tables. Use on your own risk. 
    The accuracy has been checked as good as possible but can not be guaranteed. 
    This means, if you get lost on the oceans because of errors in this publication I can not be held liable. 
    For security relevant applications you should buy an official version of the nautical almanac.

    \end{description}
    \end{titlepage}
    \newpage
    \sffamily
    \noindent
    \begin{flushright}
    \textbf{2020 May 03 to May. 17}
    \end{flushright}

    \begin{scriptsize}
    \noindent
    \begin{tabular*}{0.2\textwidth}[t]{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}|c|rr|}
\hline 
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\rule{0pt}{2.6ex}\textbf{03}} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{GHA}} &\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Dec}}\\ 
        \hline\rule{0pt}{2.6ex}\noindent
0 & 180°46.5 & \textbf{N}15°44.8\\ 
1 & 195°46.6 & 45.6\\ 
2 & 210°46.6 & 46.3\\ 
3 & 225°46.7 & \raisebox{0.24ex}{\boldmath$\cdot$~\boldmath$\cdot$~~}47.0\\ 
4 & 240°46.7 & 47.8\\ 
5 & 255°46.8 & 48.5\\[2Pt] 
6 & 270°46.9 & \textbf{N}15°49.2\\ 
7 & 285°46.9 & 50.0\\ 
8 & 300°47.0 & 50.7\\ 
9 & 315°47.1 & \raisebox{0.24ex}{\boldmath$\cdot$~\boldmath$\cdot$~~}51.4\\ 
10 & 330°47.1 & 52.1\\ 
11 & 345°47.2 & 52.9\\[2Pt] 
12 & 0°47.2 & \textbf{N}15°53.6\\ 
13 & 15°47.3 & 54.3\\ 
14 & 30°47.4 & 55.1\\ 
15 & 45°47.4 & \raisebox{0.24ex}{\boldmath$\cdot$~\boldmath$\cdot$~~}55.8\\ 
16 & 60°47.5 & 56.5\\ 
17 & 75°47.5 & 57.2\\[2Pt] 
18 & 90°47.6 & \textbf{N}15°58.0\\ 
19 & 105°47.7 & 58.7\\ 
20 & 120°47.7 & 15°59.4\\ 
21 & 135°47.8 & 16°00.1\\ 
22 & 150°47.8 & 00.8\\ 
23 & 165°47.9 & 01.6\\ 
\hline
        \rule{0pt}{2.4ex} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{SD.=15.9} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{d=0.7} \\
        \hline
\multicolumn{1}{c}{}\\[-0.5ex]\hline 
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\rule{0pt}{2.6ex}\textbf{04}} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{GHA}} &\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Dec}}\\ 
        \hline\rule{0pt}{2.6ex}\noindent
0 & 180°47.9 & \textbf{N}16°02.3\\ 
1 & 195°48.0 & 03.0\\ 
2 & 210°48.1 & 03.7\\ 
3 & 225°48.1 & \raisebox{0.24ex}{\boldmath$\cdot$~\boldmath$\cdot$~~}04.4\\ 
4 & 240°48.2 & 05.2\\ 
5 & 255°48.2 & 05.9\\[2Pt] 
6 & 270°48.3 & \textbf{N}16°06.6\\ 
7 & 285°48.3 & 07.3\\ 
8 & 300°48.4 & 08.0\\ 
9 & 315°48.5 & \raisebox{0.24ex}{\boldmath$\cdot$~\boldmath$\cdot$~~}08.8\\ 
10 & 330°48.5 & 09.5\\ 
11 & 345°48.6 & 10.2\\[2Pt] 
12 & 0°48.6 & \textbf{N}16°10.9\\ 
13 & 15°48.7 & 11.6\\ 
14 & 30°48.7 & 12.3\\ 
15 & 45°48.8 & \raisebox{0.24ex}{\boldmath$\cdot$~\boldmath$\cdot$~~}13.1\\ 
16 & 60°48.8 & 13.8\\ 
17 & 75°48.9 & 14.5\\[2Pt] 
18 & 90°49.0 & \textbf{N}16°15.2\\ 
19 & 105°49.0 & 15.9\\ 
20 & 120°49.1 & 16.6\\ 
21 & 135°49.1 & \raisebox{0.24ex}{\boldmath$\cdot$~\boldmath$\cdot$~~}17.3\\ 
22 & 150°49.2 & 18.0\\ 
23 & 165°49.2 & 18.8\\ 
\hline
        \rule{0pt}{2.4ex} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{SD.=15.9} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{d=0.7} \\
        \hline
\multicolumn{1}{c}{}\\[-0.5ex]\hline 
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\rule{0pt}{2.6ex}\textbf{05}} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{GHA}} &\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Dec}}\\ 
        \hline\rule{0pt}{2.6ex}\noindent
0 & 180°49.3 & \textbf{N}16°19.5\\ 
1 & 195°49.3 & 20.2\\ 
2 & 210°49.4 & 20.9\\ 
3 & 225°49.4 & \raisebox{0.24ex}{\boldmath$\cdot$~\boldmath$\cdot$~~}21.6\\ 
4 & 240°49.5 & 22.3\\ 
5 & 255°49.5 & 23.0\\[2Pt] 
6 & 270°49.6 & \textbf{N}16°23.7\\ 
7 & 285°49.6 & 24.4\\ 
8 & 300°49.7 & 25.1\\ 
9 & 315°49.7 & \raisebox{0.24ex}{\boldmath$\cdot$~\boldmath$\cdot$~~}25.8\\ 
10 & 330°49.8 & 26.5\\ 
11 & 345°49.8 & 27.2\\[2Pt] 
12 & 0°49.9 & \textbf{N}16°27.9\\ 
13 & 15°49.9 & 28.6\\ 
14 & 30°50.0 & 29.4\\ 
15 & 45°50.0 & \raisebox{0.24ex}{\boldmath$\cdot$~\boldmath$\cdot$~~}30.1\\ 
16 & 60°50.1 & 30.8\\ 
17 & 75°50.1 & 31.5\\[2Pt] 
18 & 90°50.2 & \textbf{N}16°32.2\\ 
19 & 105°50.2 & 32.9\\ 
20 & 120°50.3 & 33.6\\ 
21 & 135°50.3 & \raisebox{0.24ex}{\boldmath$\cdot$~\boldmath$\cdot$~~}34.3\\ 
22 & 150°50.4 & 35.0\\ 
23 & 165°50.4 & 35.7\\ 
\hline
        \rule{0pt}{2.4ex} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{SD.=15.9} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{d=0.7} \\
        \hline
\end{tabular*}\noindent
    \begin{tabular*}{0.2\textwidth}[t]{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}|c|rr|}
\hline 
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\rule{0pt}{2.6ex}\textbf{06}} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{GHA}} &\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Dec}}\\ 
        \hline\rule{0pt}{2.6ex}\noindent
0 & 180°50.5 & \textbf{N}16°36.4\\ 
1 & 195°50.5 & 37.1\\ 
2 & 210°50.5 & 37.8\\ 
3 & 225°50.6 & \raisebox{0.24ex}{\boldmath$\cdot$~\boldmath$\cdot$~~}38.5\\ 
4 & 240°50.6 & 39.2\\ 
5 & 255°50.7 & 39.8\\[2Pt] 
6 & 270°50.7 & \textbf{N}16°40.5\\ 
7 & 285°50.8 & 41.2\\ 
8 & 300°50.8 & 41.9\\ 
9 & 315°50.9 & \raisebox{0.24ex}{\boldmath$\cdot$~\boldmath$\cdot$~~}42.6\\ 
10 & 330°50.9 & 43.3\\ 
11 & 345°50.9 & 44.0\\[2Pt] 
12 & 0°51.0 & \textbf{N}16°44.7\\ 
13 & 15°51.0 & 45.4\\ 
14 & 30°51.1 & 46.1\\ 
15 & 45°51.1 & \raisebox{0.24ex}{\boldmath$\cdot$~\boldmath$\cdot$~~}46.8\\ 
16 & 60°51.2 & 47.5\\ 
17 & 75°51.2 & 48.2\\[2Pt] 
18 & 90°51.2 & \textbf{N}16°48.9\\ 
19 & 105°51.3 & 49.5\\ 
20 & 120°51.3 & 50.2\\ 
21 & 135°51.4 & \raisebox{0.24ex}{\boldmath$\cdot$~\boldmath$\cdot$~~}50.9\\ 
22 & 150°51.4 & 51.6\\ 
23 & 165°51.5 & 52.3\\ 
\hline
        \rule{0pt}{2.4ex} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{SD.=15.9} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{d=0.7} \\
        \hline
\multicolumn{1}{c}{}\\[-0.5ex]\hline 
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\rule{0pt}{2.6ex}\textbf{07}} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{GHA}} &\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Dec}}\\ 
        \hline\rule{0pt}{2.6ex}\noindent
0 & 180°51.5 & \textbf{N}16°53.0\\ 
1 & 195°51.5 & 53.7\\ 
2 & 210°51.6 & 54.4\\ 
3 & 225°51.6 & \raisebox{0.24ex}{\boldmath$\cdot$~\boldmath$\cdot$~~}55.0\\ 
4 & 240°51.7 & 55.7\\ 
5 & 255°51.7 & 56.4\\[2Pt] 
6 & 270°51.7 & \textbf{N}16°57.1\\ 
7 & 285°51.8 & 57.8\\ 
8 & 300°51.8 & 58.5\\ 
9 & 315°51.9 & \raisebox{0.24ex}{\boldmath$\cdot$~\boldmath$\cdot$~~}59.1\\ 
10 & 330°51.9 & 16°59.8\\ 
11 & 345°51.9 & 17°00.5\\[2Pt] 
12 & 0°52.0 & \textbf{N}17°01.2\\ 
13 & 15°52.0 & 01.9\\ 
14 & 30°52.0 & 02.6\\ 
15 & 45°52.1 & \raisebox{0.24ex}{\boldmath$\cdot$~\boldmath$\cdot$~~}03.2\\ 
16 & 60°52.1 & 03.9\\ 
17 & 75°52.2 & 04.6\\[2Pt] 
18 & 90°52.2 & \textbf{N}17°05.3\\ 
19 & 105°52.2 & 05.9\\ 
20 & 120°52.3 & 06.6\\ 
21 & 135°52.3 & \raisebox{0.24ex}{\boldmath$\cdot$~\boldmath$\cdot$~~}07.3\\ 
22 & 150°52.3 & 08.0\\ 
23 & 165°52.4 & 08.7\\ 
\hline
        \rule{0pt}{2.4ex} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{SD.=15.9} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{d=0.7} \\
        \hline
\multicolumn{1}{c}{}\\[-0.5ex]\hline 
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\rule{0pt}{2.6ex}\textbf{08}} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{GHA}} &\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Dec}}\\ 
        \hline\rule{0pt}{2.6ex}\noindent
0 & 180°52.4 & \textbf{N}17°09.3\\ 
1 & 195°52.4 & 10.0\\ 
2 & 210°52.5 & 10.7\\ 
3 & 225°52.5 & \raisebox{0.24ex}{\boldmath$\cdot$~\boldmath$\cdot$~~}11.3\\ 
4 & 240°52.5 & 12.0\\ 
5 & 255°52.6 & 12.7\\[2Pt] 
6 & 270°52.6 & \textbf{N}17°13.4\\ 
7 & 285°52.6 & 14.0\\ 
8 & 300°52.7 & 14.7\\ 
9 & 315°52.7 & \raisebox{0.24ex}{\boldmath$\cdot$~\boldmath$\cdot$~~}15.4\\ 
10 & 330°52.7 & 16.1\\ 
11 & 345°52.8 & 16.7\\[2Pt] 
12 & 0°52.8 & \textbf{N}17°17.4\\ 
13 & 15°52.8 & 18.1\\ 
14 & 30°52.9 & 18.7\\ 
15 & 45°52.9 & \raisebox{0.24ex}{\boldmath$\cdot$~\boldmath$\cdot$~~}19.4\\ 
16 & 60°52.9 & 20.1\\ 
17 & 75°53.0 & 20.7\\[2Pt] 
18 & 90°53.0 & \textbf{N}17°21.4\\ 
19 & 105°53.0 & 22.1\\ 
20 & 120°53.0 & 22.7\\ 
21 & 135°53.1 & \raisebox{0.24ex}{\boldmath$\cdot$~\boldmath$\cdot$~~}23.4\\ 
22 & 150°53.1 & 24.1\\ 
23 & 165°53.1 & 24.7\\ 
\hline
        \rule{0pt}{2.4ex} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{SD.=15.8} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{d=0.7} \\
        \hline
\end{tabular*}\noindent
    \begin{tabular*}{0.2\textwidth}[t]{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}|c|rr|}
\hline 
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\rule{0pt}{2.6ex}\textbf{09}} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{GHA}} &\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Dec}}\\ 
        \hline\rule{0pt}{2.6ex}\noindent
0 & 180°53.2 & \textbf{N}17°25.4\\ 
1 & 195°53.2 & 26.0\\ 
2 & 210°53.2 & 26.7\\ 
3 & 225°53.2 & \raisebox{0.24ex}{\boldmath$\cdot$~\boldmath$\cdot$~~}27.4\\ 
4 & 240°53.3 & 28.0\\ 
5 & 255°53.3 & 28.7\\[2Pt] 
6 & 270°53.3 & \textbf{N}17°29.3\\ 
7 & 285°53.4 & 30.0\\ 
8 & 300°53.4 & 30.7\\ 
9 & 315°53.4 & \raisebox{0.24ex}{\boldmath$\cdot$~\boldmath$\cdot$~~}31.3\\ 
10 & 330°53.4 & 32.0\\ 
11 & 345°53.5 & 32.6\\[2Pt] 
12 & 0°53.5 & \textbf{N}17°33.3\\ 
13 & 15°53.5 & 34.0\\ 
14 & 30°53.5 & 34.6\\ 
15 & 45°53.6 & \raisebox{0.24ex}{\boldmath$\cdot$~\boldmath$\cdot$~~}35.3\\ 
16 & 60°53.6 & 35.9\\ 
17 & 75°53.6 & 36.6\\[2Pt] 
18 & 90°53.6 & \textbf{N}17°37.2\\ 
19 & 105°53.7 & 37.9\\ 
20 & 120°53.7 & 38.5\\ 
21 & 135°53.7 & \raisebox{0.24ex}{\boldmath$\cdot$~\boldmath$\cdot$~~}39.2\\ 
22 & 150°53.7 & 39.8\\ 
23 & 165°53.8 & 40.5\\ 
\hline
        \rule{0pt}{2.4ex} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{SD.=15.8} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{d=0.7} \\
        \hline
\multicolumn{1}{c}{}\\[-0.5ex]\hline 
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\rule{0pt}{2.6ex}\textbf{10}} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{GHA}} &\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Dec}}\\ 
        \hline\rule{0pt}{2.6ex}\noindent
0 & 180°53.8 & \textbf{N}17°41.1\\ 
1 & 195°53.8 & 41.8\\ 
2 & 210°53.8 & 42.4\\ 
3 & 225°53.8 & \raisebox{0.24ex}{\boldmath$\cdot$~\boldmath$\cdot$~~}43.1\\ 
4 & 240°53.9 & 43.7\\ 
5 & 255°53.9 & 44.4\\[2Pt] 
6 & 270°53.9 & \textbf{N}17°45.0\\ 
7 & 285°53.9 & 45.7\\ 
8 & 300°53.9 & 46.3\\ 
9 & 315°54.0 & \raisebox{0.24ex}{\boldmath$\cdot$~\boldmath$\cdot$~~}47.0\\ 
10 & 330°54.0 & 47.6\\ 
11 & 345°54.0 & 48.3\\[2Pt] 
12 & 0°54.0 & \textbf{N}17°48.9\\ 
13 & 15°54.0 & 49.6\\ 
14 & 30°54.1 & 50.2\\ 
15 & 45°54.1 & \raisebox{0.24ex}{\boldmath$\cdot$~\boldmath$\cdot$~~}50.8\\ 
16 & 60°54.1 & 51.5\\ 
17 & 75°54.1 & 52.1\\[2Pt] 
18 & 90°54.1 & \textbf{N}17°52.8\\ 
19 & 105°54.2 & 53.4\\ 
20 & 120°54.2 & 54.1\\ 
21 & 135°54.2 & \raisebox{0.24ex}{\boldmath$\cdot$~\boldmath$\cdot$~~}54.7\\ 
22 & 150°54.2 & 55.3\\ 
23 & 165°54.2 & 56.0\\ 
\hline
        \rule{0pt}{2.4ex} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{SD.=15.8} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{d=0.7} \\
        \hline
\multicolumn{1}{c}{}\\[-0.5ex]\hline 
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\rule{0pt}{2.6ex}\textbf{11}} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{GHA}} &\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Dec}}\\ 
        \hline\rule{0pt}{2.6ex}\noindent
0 & 180°54.2 & \textbf{N}17°56.6\\ 
1 & 195°54.3 & 57.3\\ 
2 & 210°54.3 & 57.9\\ 
3 & 225°54.3 & \raisebox{0.24ex}{\boldmath$\cdot$~\boldmath$\cdot$~~}58.5\\ 
4 & 240°54.3 & 59.2\\ 
5 & 255°54.3 & 17°59.8\\[2Pt] 
6 & 270°54.3 & \textbf{N}18°00.4\\ 
7 & 285°54.4 & 01.1\\ 
8 & 300°54.4 & 01.7\\ 
9 & 315°54.4 & \raisebox{0.24ex}{\boldmath$\cdot$~\boldmath$\cdot$~~}02.3\\ 
10 & 330°54.4 & 03.0\\ 
11 & 345°54.4 & 03.6\\[2Pt] 
12 & 0°54.4 & \textbf{N}18°04.2\\ 
13 & 15°54.4 & 04.9\\ 
14 & 30°54.5 & 05.5\\ 
15 & 45°54.5 & \raisebox{0.24ex}{\boldmath$\cdot$~\boldmath$\cdot$~~}06.1\\ 
16 & 60°54.5 & 06.8\\ 
17 & 75°54.5 & 07.4\\[2Pt] 
18 & 90°54.5 & \textbf{N}18°08.0\\ 
19 & 105°54.5 & 08.6\\ 
20 & 120°54.5 & 09.3\\ 
21 & 135°54.5 & \raisebox{0.24ex}{\boldmath$\cdot$~\boldmath$\cdot$~~}09.9\\ 
22 & 150°54.5 & 10.5\\ 
23 & 165°54.6 & 11.2\\ 
\hline
        \rule{0pt}{2.4ex} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{SD.=15.8} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{d=0.6} \\
        \hline
\end{tabular*}\noindent
    \begin{tabular*}{0.2\textwidth}[t]{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}|c|rr|}
\hline 
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\rule{0pt}{2.6ex}\textbf{12}} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{GHA}} &\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Dec}}\\ 
        \hline\rule{0pt}{2.6ex}\noindent
0 & 180°54.6 & \textbf{N}18°11.8\\ 
1 & 195°54.6 & 12.4\\ 
2 & 210°54.6 & 13.0\\ 
3 & 225°54.6 & \raisebox{0.24ex}{\boldmath$\cdot$~\boldmath$\cdot$~~}13.7\\ 
4 & 240°54.6 & 14.3\\ 
5 & 255°54.6 & 14.9\\[2Pt] 
6 & 270°54.6 & \textbf{N}18°15.5\\ 
7 & 285°54.6 & 16.2\\ 
8 & 300°54.6 & 16.8\\ 
9 & 315°54.7 & \raisebox{0.24ex}{\boldmath$\cdot$~\boldmath$\cdot$~~}17.4\\ 
10 & 330°54.7 & 18.0\\ 
11 & 345°54.7 & 18.6\\[2Pt] 
12 & 0°54.7 & \textbf{N}18°19.3\\ 
13 & 15°54.7 & 19.9\\ 
14 & 30°54.7 & 20.5\\ 
15 & 45°54.7 & \raisebox{0.24ex}{\boldmath$\cdot$~\boldmath$\cdot$~~}21.1\\ 
16 & 60°54.7 & 21.7\\ 
17 & 75°54.7 & 22.3\\[2Pt] 
18 & 90°54.7 & \textbf{N}18°23.0\\ 
19 & 105°54.7 & 23.6\\ 
20 & 120°54.7 & 24.2\\ 
21 & 135°54.7 & \raisebox{0.24ex}{\boldmath$\cdot$~\boldmath$\cdot$~~}24.8\\ 
22 & 150°54.7 & 25.4\\ 
23 & 165°54.7 & 26.0\\ 
\hline
        \rule{0pt}{2.4ex} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{SD.=15.8} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{d=0.6} \\
        \hline
\multicolumn{1}{c}{}\\[-0.5ex]\hline 
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\rule{0pt}{2.6ex}\textbf{13}} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{GHA}} &\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Dec}}\\ 
        \hline\rule{0pt}{2.6ex}\noindent
0 & 180°54.7 & \textbf{N}18°26.6\\ 
1 & 195°54.7 & 27.3\\ 
2 & 210°54.8 & 27.9\\ 
3 & 225°54.8 & \raisebox{0.24ex}{\boldmath$\cdot$~\boldmath$\cdot$~~}28.5\\ 
4 & 240°54.8 & 29.1\\ 
5 & 255°54.8 & 29.7\\[2Pt] 
6 & 270°54.8 & \textbf{N}18°30.3\\ 
7 & 285°54.8 & 30.9\\ 
8 & 300°54.8 & 31.5\\ 
9 & 315°54.8 & \raisebox{0.24ex}{\boldmath$\cdot$~\boldmath$\cdot$~~}32.1\\ 
10 & 330°54.8 & 32.8\\ 
11 & 345°54.8 & 33.4\\[2Pt] 
12 & 0°54.8 & \textbf{N}18°34.0\\ 
13 & 15°54.8 & 34.6\\ 
14 & 30°54.8 & 35.2\\ 
15 & 45°54.8 & \raisebox{0.24ex}{\boldmath$\cdot$~\boldmath$\cdot$~~}35.8\\ 
16 & 60°54.8 & 36.4\\ 
17 & 75°54.8 & 37.0\\[2Pt] 
18 & 90°54.8 & \textbf{N}18°37.6\\ 
19 & 105°54.8 & 38.2\\ 
20 & 120°54.8 & 38.8\\ 
21 & 135°54.8 & \raisebox{0.24ex}{\boldmath$\cdot$~\boldmath$\cdot$~~}39.4\\ 
22 & 150°54.8 & 40.0\\ 
23 & 165°54.8 & 40.6\\ 
\hline
        \rule{0pt}{2.4ex} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{SD.=15.8} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{d=0.6} \\
        \hline
\multicolumn{1}{c}{}\\[-0.5ex]\hline 
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\rule{0pt}{2.6ex}\textbf{14}} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{GHA}} &\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Dec}}\\ 
        \hline\rule{0pt}{2.6ex}\noindent
0 & 180°54.8 & \textbf{N}18°41.2\\ 
1 & 195°54.8 & 41.8\\ 
2 & 210°54.8 & 42.4\\ 
3 & 225°54.8 & \raisebox{0.24ex}{\boldmath$\cdot$~\boldmath$\cdot$~~}43.0\\ 
4 & 240°54.8 & 43.6\\ 
5 & 255°54.8 & 44.2\\[2Pt] 
6 & 270°54.8 & \textbf{N}18°44.8\\ 
7 & 285°54.8 & 45.4\\ 
8 & 300°54.8 & 46.0\\ 
9 & 315°54.7 & \raisebox{0.24ex}{\boldmath$\cdot$~\boldmath$\cdot$~~}46.6\\ 
10 & 330°54.7 & 47.2\\ 
11 & 345°54.7 & 47.8\\[2Pt] 
12 & 0°54.7 & \textbf{N}18°48.4\\ 
13 & 15°54.7 & 49.0\\ 
14 & 30°54.7 & 49.5\\ 
15 & 45°54.7 & \raisebox{0.24ex}{\boldmath$\cdot$~\boldmath$\cdot$~~}50.1\\ 
16 & 60°54.7 & 50.7\\ 
17 & 75°54.7 & 51.3\\[2Pt] 
18 & 90°54.7 & \textbf{N}18°51.9\\ 
19 & 105°54.7 & 52.5\\ 
20 & 120°54.7 & 53.1\\ 
21 & 135°54.7 & \raisebox{0.24ex}{\boldmath$\cdot$~\boldmath$\cdot$~~}53.7\\ 
22 & 150°54.7 & 54.3\\ 
23 & 165°54.7 & 54.9\\ 
\hline
        \rule{0pt}{2.4ex} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{SD.=15.8} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{d=0.6} \\
        \hline
\end{tabular*}\noindent
    \begin{tabular*}{0.2\textwidth}[t]{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}|c|rr|}
\hline 
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\rule{0pt}{2.6ex}\textbf{15}} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{GHA}} &\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Dec}}\\ 
        \hline\rule{0pt}{2.6ex}\noindent
0 & 180°54.7 & \textbf{N}18°55.4\\ 
1 & 195°54.6 & 56.0\\ 
2 & 210°54.6 & 56.6\\ 
3 & 225°54.6 & \raisebox{0.24ex}{\boldmath$\cdot$~\boldmath$\cdot$~~}57.2\\ 
4 & 240°54.6 & 57.8\\ 
5 & 255°54.6 & 58.4\\[2Pt] 
6 & 270°54.6 & \textbf{N}18°59.0\\ 
7 & 285°54.6 & 18°59.5\\ 
8 & 300°54.6 & 19°00.1\\ 
9 & 315°54.6 & \raisebox{0.24ex}{\boldmath$\cdot$~\boldmath$\cdot$~~}00.7\\ 
10 & 330°54.6 & 01.3\\ 
11 & 345°54.6 & 01.9\\[2Pt] 
12 & 0°54.5 & \textbf{N}19°02.4\\ 
13 & 15°54.5 & 03.0\\ 
14 & 30°54.5 & 03.6\\ 
15 & 45°54.5 & \raisebox{0.24ex}{\boldmath$\cdot$~\boldmath$\cdot$~~}04.2\\ 
16 & 60°54.5 & 04.8\\ 
17 & 75°54.5 & 05.3\\[2Pt] 
18 & 90°54.5 & \textbf{N}19°05.9\\ 
19 & 105°54.5 & 06.5\\ 
20 & 120°54.4 & 07.1\\ 
21 & 135°54.4 & \raisebox{0.24ex}{\boldmath$\cdot$~\boldmath$\cdot$~~}07.6\\ 
22 & 150°54.4 & 08.2\\ 
23 & 165°54.4 & 08.8\\ 
\hline
        \rule{0pt}{2.4ex} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{SD.=15.8} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{d=0.6} \\
        \hline
\multicolumn{1}{c}{}\\[-0.5ex]\hline 
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\rule{0pt}{2.6ex}\textbf{16}} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{GHA}} &\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Dec}}\\ 
        \hline\rule{0pt}{2.6ex}\noindent
0 & 180°54.4 & \textbf{N}19°09.4\\ 
1 & 195°54.4 & 09.9\\ 
2 & 210°54.4 & 10.5\\ 
3 & 225°54.3 & \raisebox{0.24ex}{\boldmath$\cdot$~\boldmath$\cdot$~~}11.1\\ 
4 & 240°54.3 & 11.7\\ 
5 & 255°54.3 & 12.2\\[2Pt] 
6 & 270°54.3 & \textbf{N}19°12.8\\ 
7 & 285°54.3 & 13.4\\ 
8 & 300°54.3 & 13.9\\ 
9 & 315°54.3 & \raisebox{0.24ex}{\boldmath$\cdot$~\boldmath$\cdot$~~}14.5\\ 
10 & 330°54.2 & 15.1\\ 
11 & 345°54.2 & 15.6\\[2Pt] 
12 & 0°54.2 & \textbf{N}19°16.2\\ 
13 & 15°54.2 & 16.8\\ 
14 & 30°54.2 & 17.3\\ 
15 & 45°54.2 & \raisebox{0.24ex}{\boldmath$\cdot$~\boldmath$\cdot$~~}17.9\\ 
16 & 60°54.1 & 18.5\\ 
17 & 75°54.1 & 19.0\\[2Pt] 
18 & 90°54.1 & \textbf{N}19°19.6\\ 
19 & 105°54.1 & 20.2\\ 
20 & 120°54.1 & 20.7\\ 
21 & 135°54.0 & \raisebox{0.24ex}{\boldmath$\cdot$~\boldmath$\cdot$~~}21.3\\ 
22 & 150°54.0 & 21.8\\ 
23 & 165°54.0 & 22.4\\ 
\hline
        \rule{0pt}{2.4ex} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{SD.=15.8} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{d=0.6} \\
        \hline
\multicolumn{1}{c}{}\\[-0.5ex]\hline 
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\rule{0pt}{2.6ex}\textbf{17}} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{GHA}} &\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Dec}}\\ 
        \hline\rule{0pt}{2.6ex}\noindent
0 & 180°54.0 & \textbf{N}19°23.0\\ 
1 & 195°54.0 & 23.5\\ 
2 & 210°53.9 & 24.1\\ 
3 & 225°53.9 & \raisebox{0.24ex}{\boldmath$\cdot$~\boldmath$\cdot$~~}24.6\\ 
4 & 240°53.9 & 25.2\\ 
5 & 255°53.9 & 25.8\\[2Pt] 
6 & 270°53.9 & \textbf{N}19°26.3\\ 
7 & 285°53.8 & 26.9\\ 
8 & 300°53.8 & 27.4\\ 
9 & 315°53.8 & \raisebox{0.24ex}{\boldmath$\cdot$~\boldmath$\cdot$~~}28.0\\ 
10 & 330°53.8 & 28.5\\ 
11 & 345°53.7 & 29.1\\[2Pt] 
12 & 0°53.7 & \textbf{N}19°29.6\\ 
13 & 15°53.7 & 30.2\\ 
14 & 30°53.7 & 30.7\\ 
15 & 45°53.7 & \raisebox{0.24ex}{\boldmath$\cdot$~\boldmath$\cdot$~~}31.3\\ 
16 & 60°53.6 & 31.9\\ 
17 & 75°53.6 & 32.4\\[2Pt] 
18 & 90°53.6 & \textbf{N}19°33.0\\ 
19 & 105°53.6 & 33.5\\ 
20 & 120°53.5 & 34.0\\ 
21 & 135°53.5 & \raisebox{0.24ex}{\boldmath$\cdot$~\boldmath$\cdot$~~}34.6\\ 
22 & 150°53.5 & 35.1\\ 
23 & 165°53.5 & 35.7\\ 
\hline
        \rule{0pt}{2.4ex} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{SD.=15.8} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{d=0.6} \\
        \hline
\end{tabular*}\end{scriptsize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: you haven't posted any code that allows anyone to test (and none of the packages that you list are related to fonts). Please post a small example that shows a difference then we could run the document on an old and new tex installation and compare

Comment: the ucs package you are using (through the imho not recommendable utf8x option) is doing what David is describing in his answer: its def-file contains `\ProvideTextCommandDefault{\textdegree}{\ensuremath{{^\circ}}}`. If you prefer the circ (I wouldn't) you can force the definition.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would guess that you have done something equivalent to  this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{textcomp}
\providecommand\textdegree{\ensuremath{^\circ}}
\begin{document}

3\textdegree

\end{document}
```

which uses `\textdegree` if it is available, in which case you get

[image]

But if `\textdegree` is not defined, it is faked using a math superscript `\circ` which produces.

[image]

Previously to get `\textdegree` you had to load the `textcomp` package explicitly but from the 2020-02-02 release this is preloaded. (The only reason it was not preloaded originally was the memory requirements of a 640K PC in the 1990s...)

It seems that you prefer the "faked" symbol, so you could use

`$^\circ$` always rather than conditionally using `\textdegree` if it exists.

Comment: well I wasn't using either. Of course I could add what you suggest would be a good substitute for the degree symbol. However I am unhappy with the smaller font size (less width) that is now output - the wider scriptsize font was much more legible when small numbers have to be placed on a page. THANKS for your comments!

Comment: @Aendie ah you finally showed some code:-) OK you used ° which `inputenc`  defines to be `\textdegree` with a fallback to use ^\circ exactly as I describe here, so my guess was basically correct.

Comment: @Aendie so you could if you want use `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00B0}{\ensuremath{{}^\circ}}` to force it never to use the font specified degree symbol.

Comment: Okay, it might be just the degree symbol that's the problem. (Adobe Acrobat Reader DC is great for comparing PDFs as both samples can be positioned exactly on the same position on the screen. I see even one pixel discrepancies.) I guess I was wrong to just output the degree symbol by itself?

Comment: @Aendie note in relation to your comments about stability note that the only reason that you get changed output here is because you are using a non standard definition (from utf8x) that was explicitly conditional, it is saying use "^\circ  unless \textdegree becomes available" so now \textdegree is available by default it is used. So the issue is essentially local to do documents that  use the (non standard and somewhat deprecated) utf8x option and had _not_ loaded the standard textcomp package to define \textdegree, as they now get textdegree defined.

Comment: @@David... Do I also need \usepackage{amssymb} ?

Comment: @Aendie I don't understand your comment about "small numbers" nothing that comes from the superscript math font is changed here, it is just the degree symbol is no longer faked from the math font but comes from the font family you are using for text and is "naturally raised" just as it is in your source.

Comment: @Aendie you may or may not need amssymb depending on whether you use any of its characters but it is unrelated to the degree symbol

Comment: @@David. Okay - understood (small numbers). However inserting the \DeclareUnicodeCharacter line just doesn't compile for me. ! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

Comment: @Aendie it will work (although looks like I am missing a final `}` in the above. (but actually using a real degree character rather than a faked math superscript isn't "destroying" anything, so you could just use the intended character

Comment: @@David . Got it - using   \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}   and   \usepackage{textcomp}. I hope that's what you recommend - I'm no expert on LaTeX. THANKS a million!

Comment: @Aendie you don't need either of those packages, utf8 inputenc and loading textcomp are both default behaviour so they do nothing

Comment: Sincere thanks for your advice which has been very helpful. My apologies for thinking the PDF had been radically modified. I take it MiKTeX only moves forward, i.e. unlike Python packages you can't (and shouldn't) select a previous version.

Comment: @Aendie I have no idea if old miktex input trees are available you can get old texlive ISO but this is very rarely necessary or recommended. miktex isn't really involved here (I generated the examples with texlive) it's the latex release that changed, to reload the textcomp package.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `siunitx` package to define the degree centigrade symbol. Here I propose two different alternatives.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
$\mathrm{15}\si{\degree}$
$\ang{3}$
\end{document}
```